# How to check the version compatibility of an exe?

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, visual-studio-2008, webserver

How to compare the version of an application in server and the application installed in client machine?

Comment: [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways.

1. Server can have a public WCF service, that returns the version of the app on the server. It can take it from exe file that is lying on the server (using reflection), or just parsing some server xml file - that can be updated by deployment responsible person. You can consume that service in your client app when needed.
2. ClickOnce deployment gives you abbility not to think about versioning. You can configure such deployment in a way that application won't start if there is a new version on server(that will be downloaded automatically).

Others are variations of connection to the server method and deployment configuration. Choose what fits you most.

Don't forget to mark this as correct in case it fits you.

Comment: thanks for the answer LexRema. It really helped me.. Can u post what are the other ways also?

Comment: For example, you can just place that xml on some public server and download and parse it on a clent (that's a litle bit ugly). Also consumption of not WCF but Webmethods can be helpful.

Comment: i have placed an exe in web server. so that i can download it to local system and run that exe. If i have changed the version with few enhacements in that exe and placed in server, then whenever i am trying to run the exe it should ask for download the updated version in the server.  I am not using the Clickonce deployment..

Comment: Yeah, but click once is exactly what you need. It would be simpliest one. Or really, to check version on the server first.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comments LexRema. i verified with ClickOnce Deployment. its really did that what i need. its wonderful. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check the assembly info running on both machines. by using Reflection you can do it .

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/262228-how-check-assemblys-version

Or try this for each machine .

using System.Reflection;

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version. ToString()